# importing a cpp project build with cmake in android using ndk

Tags: android-ndk, cmake, opencv3.1

I have a Cpp project that use OpenCV. I build it using cmake here is the CMakeLists.txt:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

find_package( OpenCV 3.1.0 REQUIRED core text)
include_directories( ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})
set(OpenCV_LIBS opencv_core opencv_objdetect)

add_library(opencv lib/utils/opencv.cpp lib/utils/opencv.h)

set(SOURCES main.cpp )

add_executable( ${PROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCES} )
target_link_libraries( ${PROJECT_NAME} ${OpenCV_LIBS} )
target_link_libraries( ${PROJECT_NAME} opencv )
```

On Android studio I have some External Native Build Issues:
...

```
CMake Error at /home/benng/bin/opencv_working_dir/opencv-3.1.0/build/OpenCVConfig.cmake:86 (include):  
  include could not find load file:  
    /home/benng/bin/opencv_working_dir/opencv-3.1.0/build/OpenCVModules_armeabi.cmake
Call Stack (most recent call first):  
  src/CMakeLists.txt:5 (find_package)
OpenCV version : 3.1.0
```

...

I was wondering:
 - if I had to use the OpenCV SDK for android or just give the CMakeLists.txt of my project and android studio does the rest ?
 - What extra information do I need to give to who in order to build my project properly ? (as usual)
 - Is there an other way to reach my goal ?

By the way this is an open source project you can check it out here:
https://bitbucket.org/BenNG/sudoku-recognizer

Thank you !

Comment: did you solve this issue? I have the same problem with CMake C++ project that uses OpenCV. And I want to link this subproject with my Android Studio Project.